# Allow another user to read/write data Firebase Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database tree like so

```
users
-UID
--items
---all the data
```

I would like to add something under UID like shared:another-UID and allow the other UID to read and write everything under items.

For example:

```
users
-UID
--shared:different_UID
--items
---all the data
```

My current rules are like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I change my rules to allow this?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Maybe you could illustrate by showing a specific query that currently isn't allowed, that you would like to allow, given some new constraints.

Comment: Please check edit.  I have read up on the the security rules but not quite getting how to set them correctly.  Currently everything under UID is restricted to only that UID.  I would like to add another UID to see and edit all that data that is normal restricted by the current rules.  I know I need to add a || and reference the shared UID value.  But I am not sure how to reference that in the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case your rules would become:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || data.child('shared').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || data.child('shared').val() === auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in words: the user can read/write this data if the key is the same as their user ID, or if their user ID is stored in the `shared` property under the data.

Comment: perfect.  I assumed that was the case the only hurdle was figuring out the data.child('shared') part.  Thank you